# Is AVAudio autoreleased?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I'm new to playing sounds on iOS. I know that to play various sounds I should have a audio manager helper class keeping all the audios together.

Now, I'm wondering if it is OK to do this without memory leak:

```
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err];
[newPlayer play];
```

Will the player get released after it finished playing? Or do I need to keep a pointer to it, call `[newPlayer stop]` when it finishes, then set the pointer to `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is the opposite of a leak. If you do not retain the player, it will be released immediately and will never play.

See my answer here for more info: [Playing back audio using AVAudioPlayer iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569699/playing-back-audio-using-avaudioplayer-ios-7/22570686#22570686)