# Sound wont play using avfoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Any reason why this will not be working?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


AVAudioPlayer *showsound;
            NSString *audiopath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mouse1" ofType:@"wav"];
            NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audiopath];
            showsound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:audiourl error:Nil];
            [showsound play];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing back audio using AVAudioPlayer iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569699/playing-back-audio-using-avaudioplayer-ios-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the reason is that your audio player instance, showsound, is created as a local variable so will be deallocated as soon as the method that code is in goes out of scope. Create a strong property for show sound, and it will work properly.