# Audio wont play in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have the following code that used to work to play a sound in my project however after iv done some playing around over the past few weeks on other aspects of the project it dose not seem to play.

The audio file is in the main directory and works in preview.

Any ideas?

```
//playsound
AVAudioPlayer *showsound;
NSString *audiopath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mouse1" ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *audiourl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audiopath];
showsound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:audiourl error:Nil];
[showsound play];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playing back audio using AVAudioPlayer iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22569699/playing-back-audio-using-avaudioplayer-ios-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because after the line `showsound play` your method comes to an end and `showsound` (your AVAudioPlayer) is released. Hence there is nothing to do any playing any more. Solution: retain it! (For example, set an instance variable to hold on to it.)

Comment: Can you possibly give me an example?